# Error converting data type varchar to float when selecting all in sqlserver script

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run the below query, however it returns records then after about 1000 records it stops and displays this Error converting data type varchar to float message.  How can I solve this?

```
select * from
[storagedb - baw].dbo.nonres1 nr
join [storagedb - baw].[dbo].[BAW_AllSources_Stage1] ba
on nr.CSTMR_GRP_KEY2 = ba.Customer_CIS
```

Comment: My guess is that there is a problem with your data.  Can you post some sample data so that we may see it?

Comment: one of the nr.CSTMR_GRP_KEY2 or  ba.Customer_CIS  have float data type and another varchar  in varchar column  there are some thin that can not be converted in float.

Comment: Can you provide data type of these columns - CSTMR_GRP_KEY2 and Customer_CIS ?

Comment: CSTMR_GRP_KEY2 is float and Customer_CIS is varchar(400)

Comment: @user2447136 - Based on that, try to use `ON CAST(nr.CSTMR_GRP_KEY2 AS varchar(400)) = ba.Customer_CIS` in your join predicate. Basically what happens is everything from `Customer_CIS` is trying to be implicitly converted to _float_ but some values that you have in there simply cannot be converted.

Comment: Test for numeric https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: It is running without an error however it is not returning any records anymore.  Initially it would return records then break after about 1000.

Comment: Yes, May be after 1000 records there is one value in table which is not convertible to float data type.

Comment: How best can I solve this in my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment about data types you wrote, a likely solution would be:

```
select * from
[storagedb - baw].dbo.nonres1 nr
join [storagedb - baw].[dbo].[BAW_AllSources_Stage1] ba
  on CAST(nr.CSTMR_GRP_KEY2 AS varchar(400)) = ba.Customer_CIS
```

OR:

```
select * from
[storagedb - baw].dbo.nonres1 nr
join [storagedb - baw].[dbo].[BAW_AllSources_Stage1] ba
  on nr.CSTMR_GRP_KEY2 = TRY_CAST(ba.Customer_CIS AS float)
```

**NOTE:** for the second query you need to have SQL Server 2012 or newer.

Basically what happens is everything from `Customer_CIS` is trying to be implicitly converted to float but some values that you have in there simply cannot be converted.

If you're expecting that all the data should be convertible, in order to gain insight which values are the problem, with the assumption you have SQL Server 2012 or newer, you would get the troubling values with the next query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [storagedb - baw].[dbo].[BAW_AllSources_Stage1]
WHERE TRY_CAST(Customer_CIS AS float) IS NULL;
```

Comment: Yes.  This is showing me the problematic values.   How best can I deal with these in my join?

Comment: Well if they indeed are not supposed to be there, you need to fix them. If it's possible that they're there and you just want to "ignore" them (not join on those), you can use the first query I wrote... instead of casting improper string values to float, it casts floats to strings and then joins based on that. I'll add another query which tries to cast your strings to floats and if it's not possible they return `NULL` so that the whole predicate is evaluated as _unknown_ for such `Customer_CIS` values and therefore those rows are excluded from the query.

Comment: the 2nd query you posted is working well for me  - thank you for your help

Comment: @user2447136 - I'm glad I could help. If it's problem solved now, I suggest marking my answer as the solution so that people don't need to bother opening this issue up anymore. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to find values in your table which is not convertible to float data type. Try this -

```
select *
from [storagedb - baw].[dbo].[BAW_AllSources_Stage1]
where TRY_CONVERT(float, Customer_CIS) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

By joining a FLOAT to a VARCHAR what happens is that SQL server wants to compare apples with apples, so an implicit conversion of the VARCHAR to a FLOAT is done.

But when that VARCHAR column contains values that can't be converted to a FLOAT it will raise an error like :

```
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

So to make the conversion explicit, change the JOIN clause so that apples are compared with apples.

One can use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) or [TRY_PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql) for this.
If the attempted conversion fails then the TRY will return a NULL.

```sql
select * from
[storagedb - baw].dbo.nonres1 nr
join [storagedb - baw].[dbo].[BAW_AllSources_Stage1] ba
on nr.CSTMR_GRP_KEY2 = TRY_CONVERT(float,ba.Customer_CIS)
```

Simplified Test Snippet:

```
declare @T table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, col_float float, col_varchar varchar(400));

insert into @T (col_float, col_varchar) values (1,'1'),(2,'two'),(0,''),(null,null);

select *, 
try_convert(float, col_varchar) as col_varchar_convert_to_float,
try_parse(col_varchar as float) as col_varchar_parse_as_float
from @T t
where col_float = try_convert(float, col_varchar);
```

Comment: Btw, I didn't suggest [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) because the Intellisense in my version of MS SQL Server Management Studio doesn't  recognize it as build-in function. Which is annoying, so I rather avoid using it.  Also beware that there's an oddity when converting an empty string. I.e. `select try_convert(FLOAT,'')` will return 0.